# How to cherry pick packages when running Ant's jar task?

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am compiling (`javac`) my Java source files to `gen/bin` like so:

```
myproject/
    src/
        (all my source code)
    gen/bin/
        com.me.myorg.fizz.*
        com.me.myorg.buzz.*
        com.me.myorg.foo.*
        com.me.myorg.bar.*
```

It just so happens that there are **zero** (0) dependencies between each top-level package (fizz, buzz, foo, bar); ergo nothing in `foo` has dependencies outside of `foo`, etc.

I would like to create 4 different JAR files from this setup:

- `fizz.jar`
- `buzz.jar`
- `foo.jar`
- `bar.jar`

This means I'll need 4 `<jar>` tasks inside my `jar-all` target like so:

```
<target name="jar-all">
    <jar destfile="gen/dist/fizz.jar">
        <fileset dir="gen/bin" includes="???" />    --> How do I specify **only** com.me.myorg.fizz.* classes ???
    </jar>

    <!-- 3 other nearly-identical JAR tasks... -->
</target>
```

How do I go about cherry picking which packages get placed in each jar? Obviously, I want the following package/jar implementation:

```
com.me.myorg.fizz.* --> fizz.jar
com.me.myorg.buzz.* --> buzz.jar
com.me.myorg.foo.*  --> foo.jar
com.me.myorg.bar.*  --> bar.jar
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply include the path to the class files under the path corresponding to your fully qualified package names:

```
<jar destfile="gen/dist/fizz.jar">
    <fileset dir="gen/bin" includes="com/me/myorg/fizz/**/*.class" />
</jar>

<jar destfile="gen/dist/buzz.jar">
    <fileset dir="gen/bin" includes="com/me/myorg/buzz/**/*.class" />
</jar>

<jar destfile="gen/dist/foo.jar">
    <fileset dir="gen/bin" includes="com/me/myorg/foo/**/*.class" />
</jar>

<jar destfile="gen/dist/bar.jar">
    <fileset dir="gen/bin" includes="com/me/myorg/bar/**/*.class" />
</jar>
```

`**/*.class` means all class files including ones inside subdirectories if any.